# "When" + past simple or "while" + past continuous to introduce "used to"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, used-to

I was doing grammar exercises with a friend and I tried to make an example, but the tenses got me confused. Here are two possibilities:

> While we were living in Paris, we used to eat croissants every morning

...and...

> When we lived in Paris, we used to eat croissants every morning.

Are both of these correct or just one or neither? Could we explain grammatically why or why not?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I haven't been able to find a single one which answers my question...

Comment: You  may   find  the  answer  here
  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106169/used-to-or-past-simple-with-the-adverb-when  the  answer  here.

Comment: Both  of  your  sentences  are  correct You  stopped eating  croissants  now.It  was your  past  habit.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase my question well, but my dilemma is whether it is better to use past continuous or past simple in the introductory/preceding clause. I have no doubts about the "used to".

Comment: past continuous has a more temporary feel than past simple.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical. Which you use is up to you.